# 404 Error on registration links (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, civievent, online-registration

All of our event registration were set up tested and running and all of a sudden all of our event pages go to a 404 error when I try to see the live registration link (from the embedded link on the website and from the "Manage Events" page in CiviCRM when I go to the live link.

I am wondering if it was because I made an edit to the online registration form, which I did this morning, but that hasn't effected the links in the past...

We currently have CiviCRM version 5.37.2, Any guidance appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: it will help folk help you if you can add some anonymised (unless they can be public) links so we can see what the urls look like in case it is that. other things to check are that you have set the right permissions up for different users. and of course if you have moved your site (eg dev to live) then mention that too

Answer (score 0):

This actually was solved, because I called in a pro
It was an issue with the Permalinks through wordpress.

Comment: You should accept your (own) answer as a solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate to help future users with the same problem like me: Where did you use permalinks, and how did you change them to solve the problem?

Comment: As a Wordpress admin, navigate to Settings > Permalinks. Make sure "Post name" is selected and click "Save changes" (even if "Post name" was already selected). That will regenerate the Pernalinks.